I am getting this error while writing the test case : - Trying to run get method on non-active contract
I am writing smart contracts to mint fungible tokens(jettons) in the FunC language for the TON. While writing the test case i am getting below error :-
Trying to run get method on non-active contract
This is the minter contract :-
`#include "imports/stdlib.fc";
#include "imports/params.fc";
#include "imports/constants.fc";
#include "imports/jetton-utils.fc";
#include "imports/op-codes.fc";
#include "imports/utils.fc";
#include "imports/discovery-params.fc";

(int, slice, cell, cell) load_data() inline {
    slice ds = get_data().begin_parse();
    return (
            ds~load_coins(), 
            ds~load_msg_addr(), 
            ds~load_ref(), 
            ds~load_ref() 
    );
}

() save_data(int total_supply, slice admin_address, cell content, cell jetton_wallet_code) impure inline {
    set_data(begin_cell()
            .store_coins(total_supply)
            .store_slice(admin_address)
            .store_ref(content)
            .store_ref(jetton_wallet_code)
            .end_cell()
    );
}

() mint_tokens(slice to_address, cell jetton_wallet_code, int amount, cell master_msg) impure {
    cell state_init = calculate_jetton_wallet_state_init(to_address, my_address(), jetton_wallet_code);
    slice to_wallet_address = calculate_jetton_wallet_address(state_init);
    var msg = begin_cell()
            .store_uint(0x18, 6)
            .store_slice(to_wallet_address)
            .store_coins(amount)
            .store_uint(4 + 2 + 1, 1 + 4 + 4 + 64 + 32 + 1 + 1 + 1)
            .store_ref(state_init)
            .store_ref(master_msg);
    send_raw_message(msg.end_cell(), 1); 
}

() recv_internal(int msg_value, cell in_msg_full, slice in_msg_body) impure {
    if (in_msg_body.slice_empty?()) { 
        return ();
    }
    slice cs = in_msg_full.begin_parse();
    int flags = cs~load_uint(4);

    if (flags & 1) { 
        return ();
    }
    slice sender_address = cs~load_msg_addr();
    cs~load_msg_addr(); 
    cs~load_coins(); 
    cs~skip_bits(1); 
    cs~load_coins(); 
    int fwd_fee = cs~load_coins(); 

    int op = in_msg_body~load_uint(32);
    int query_id = in_msg_body~load_uint(64);

    (int total_supply, slice admin_address, cell content, cell jetton_wallet_code) = load_data();

    if (op == op::mint()) {
        throw_unless(73, equal_slices(sender_address, admin_address));
        slice to_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
        int amount = in_msg_body~load_coins();
        cell master_msg = in_msg_body~load_ref();
        slice master_msg_cs = master_msg.begin_parse();
        master_msg_cs~skip_bits(32 + 64); 
        int jetton_amount = master_msg_cs~load_coins();
        mint_tokens(to_address, jetton_wallet_code, amount, master_msg);
        save_data(total_supply + jetton_amount, admin_address, content, jetton_wallet_code);
        return ();
    }

    if (op == op::burn_notification()) {
        int jetton_amount = in_msg_body~load_coins();
        slice from_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
        throw_unless(74,
                equal_slices(calculate_user_jetton_wallet_address(from_address, my_address(), jetton_wallet_code), sender_address)
        );
        save_data(total_supply - jetton_amount, admin_address, content, jetton_wallet_code);
        slice response_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
        if (response_address.preload_uint(2) != 0) {
            var msg = begin_cell()
                    .store_uint(0x10, 6) 
                    .store_slice(response_address)
                    .store_coins(0)
                    .store_uint(0, 1 + 4 + 4 + 64 + 32 + 1 + 1)
                    .store_uint(op::excesses(), 32)
                    .store_uint(query_id, 64);
            send_raw_message(msg.end_cell(), 2 + 64);
        }
        return ();
    }

    if (op == op::provide_wallet_address()) {
        throw_unless(75, msg_value > fwd_fee + const::provide_address_gas_consumption());

        slice owner_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
        int include_address? = in_msg_body~load_uint(1);

        cell included_address = include_address?
                ? begin_cell().store_slice(owner_address).end_cell()
                : null();

        var msg = begin_cell()
                .store_uint(0x18, 6)
                .store_slice(sender_address)
                .store_coins(0)
                .store_uint(0, 1 + 4 + 4 + 64 + 32 + 1 + 1)
                .store_uint(op::take_wallet_address(), 32)
                .store_uint(query_id, 64);

        if (is_resolvable?(owner_address)) {
            msg = msg.store_slice(calculate_user_jetton_wallet_address(owner_address, my_address(), jetton_wallet_code));
        } else {
            msg = msg.store_uint(0, 2); 
        }
        send_raw_message(msg.store_maybe_ref(included_address).end_cell(), 64);
        return ();
    }

    if (op == 3) { 
        throw_unless(73, equal_slices(sender_address, admin_address));
        slice new_admin_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
        save_data(total_supply, new_admin_address, content, jetton_wallet_code);
        return ();
    }

    if (op == 4) { 
        throw_unless(73, equal_slices(sender_address, admin_address));
        save_data(total_supply, admin_address, in_msg_body~load_ref(), jetton_wallet_code);
        return ();
    }

    throw(0xffff);
}

(int, int, slice, cell, cell) get_jetton_data() method_id {
    (int total_supply, slice admin_address, cell content, cell jetton_wallet_code) = load_data();
    return (total_supply, -1, admin_address, content, jetton_wallet_code);
}

slice get_wallet_address(slice owner_address) method_id {
    (int total_supply, slice admin_address, cell content, cell jetton_wallet_code) = load_data();
    return calculate_user_jetton_wallet_address(owner_address, my_address(), jetton_wallet_code);
}`

This is the wallet contract :-

#include "imports/stdlib.fc";
#include "imports/params.fc";
#include "imports/constants.fc";
#include "imports/jetton-utils.fc";
#include "imports/op-codes.fc";
#include "imports/utils.fc";

const min_tons_for_storage = 10000000; 
const gas_consumption = 10000000; 


(int, slice, slice, cell) load_data() inline {
  slice ds = get_data().begin_parse();
  return (ds~load_coins(), ds~load_msg_addr(), ds~load_msg_addr(), ds~load_ref());
}

() save_data (int balance, slice owner_address, slice jetton_master_address, cell jetton_wallet_code) impure inline {
  set_data(pack_jetton_wallet_data(balance, owner_address, jetton_master_address, jetton_wallet_code));
}

() send_tokens (slice in_msg_body, slice sender_address, int msg_value, int fwd_fee) impure {
  int query_id = in_msg_body~load_uint(64);
  int jetton_amount = in_msg_body~load_coins();
  slice to_owner_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
  force_chain(to_owner_address);
  (int balance, slice owner_address, slice jetton_master_address, cell jetton_wallet_code) = load_data();
  balance -= jetton_amount;

  throw_unless(705, equal_slices(owner_address, sender_address));
  throw_unless(706, balance >= 0);

  cell state_init = calculate_jetton_wallet_state_init(to_owner_address, jetton_master_address, jetton_wallet_code);
  slice to_wallet_address = calculate_jetton_wallet_address(state_init);
  slice response_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
  cell custom_payload = in_msg_body~load_dict();
  int forward_ton_amount = in_msg_body~load_coins();
  throw_unless(708, slice_bits(in_msg_body) >= 1);
  slice either_forward_payload = in_msg_body;
  var msg = begin_cell()
    .store_uint(0x18, 6)
    .store_slice(to_wallet_address)
    .store_coins(0)
    .store_uint(4 + 2 + 1, 1 + 4 + 4 + 64 + 32 + 1 + 1 + 1)
    .store_ref(state_init);
  var msg_body = begin_cell()
    .store_uint(op::internal_transfer(), 32)
    .store_uint(query_id, 64)
    .store_coins(jetton_amount)
    .store_slice(owner_address)
    .store_slice(response_address)
    .store_coins(forward_ton_amount)
    .store_slice(either_forward_payload)
    .end_cell();

  msg = msg.store_ref(msg_body);
  int fwd_count = forward_ton_amount ? 2 : 1;
  throw_unless(709, msg_value >
                     forward_ton_amount +
                     fwd_count * fwd_fee +
                     (2 * gas_consumption + min_tons_for_storage));

  send_raw_message(msg.end_cell(), 64); 
  save_data(balance, owner_address, jetton_master_address, jetton_wallet_code);
}

() receive_tokens (slice in_msg_body, slice sender_address, int my_ton_balance, int fwd_fee, int msg_value) impure {
  (int balance, slice owner_address, slice jetton_master_address, cell jetton_wallet_code) = load_data();
  int query_id = in_msg_body~load_uint(64);
  int jetton_amount = in_msg_body~load_coins();
  balance += jetton_amount;
  slice from_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
  slice response_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
  throw_unless(707,
      equal_slices(jetton_master_address, sender_address)
      |
      equal_slices(calculate_user_jetton_wallet_address(from_address, jetton_master_address, jetton_wallet_code), sender_address)
  );
  int forward_ton_amount = in_msg_body~load_coins();

  int ton_balance_before_msg = my_ton_balance - msg_value;
  int storage_fee = min_tons_for_storage - min(ton_balance_before_msg, min_tons_for_storage);
  msg_value -= (storage_fee + gas_consumption);
  if(forward_ton_amount) {
    msg_value -= (forward_ton_amount + fwd_fee);
    slice either_forward_payload = in_msg_body;

    var msg_body = begin_cell()
        .store_uint(op::transfer_notification(), 32)
        .store_uint(query_id, 64)
        .store_coins(jetton_amount)
        .store_slice(from_address)
        .store_slice(either_forward_payload)
        .end_cell();

    var msg = begin_cell()
      .store_uint(0x10, 6) 
      .store_slice(owner_address)
      .store_coins(forward_ton_amount)
      .store_uint(1, 1 + 4 + 4 + 64 + 32 + 1 + 1)
      .store_ref(msg_body);

    send_raw_message(msg.end_cell(), 1);
  }

  if ((response_address.preload_uint(2) != 0) & (msg_value > 0)) {
    var msg = begin_cell()
      .store_uint(0x10, 6) 
      .store_slice(response_address)
      .store_coins(msg_value)
      .store_uint(0, 1 + 4 + 4 + 64 + 32 + 1 + 1)
      .store_uint(op::excesses(), 32)
      .store_uint(query_id, 64);
    send_raw_message(msg.end_cell(), 2);
  }

  save_data(balance, owner_address, jetton_master_address, jetton_wallet_code);
}

() burn_tokens (slice in_msg_body, slice sender_address, int msg_value, int fwd_fee) impure {
  (int balance, slice owner_address, slice jetton_master_address, cell jetton_wallet_code) = load_data();
  int query_id = in_msg_body~load_uint(64);
  int jetton_amount = in_msg_body~load_coins();
  slice response_address = in_msg_body~load_msg_addr();
  balance -= jetton_amount;
  throw_unless(705, equal_slices(owner_address, sender_address));
  throw_unless(706, balance >= 0);
  throw_unless(707, msg_value > fwd_fee + 2 * gas_consumption);

  var msg_body = begin_cell()
      .store_uint(op::burn_notification(), 32)
      .store_uint(query_id, 64)
      .store_coins(jetton_amount)
      .store_slice(owner_address)
      .store_slice(response_address)
      .end_cell();

  var msg = begin_cell()
    .store_uint(0x18, 6)
    .store_slice(jetton_master_address)
    .store_coins(0)
    .store_uint(1, 1 + 4 + 4 + 64 + 32 + 1 + 1)
    .store_ref(msg_body);

  send_raw_message(msg.end_cell(), 64);

  save_data(balance, owner_address, jetton_master_address, jetton_wallet_code);
}

() on_bounce (slice in_msg_body) impure {
  in_msg_body~skip_bits(32); 
  (int balance, slice owner_address, slice jetton_master_address, cell jetton_wallet_code) = load_data();
  int op = in_msg_body~load_uint(32);
  throw_unless(709, (op == op::internal_transfer()) | (op == op::burn_notification()));
  int query_id = in_msg_body~load_uint(64);
  int jetton_amount = in_msg_body~load_coins();
  balance += jetton_amount;
  save_data(balance, owner_address, jetton_master_address, jetton_wallet_code);
}

() recv_internal(int my_balance, int msg_value, cell in_msg_full, slice in_msg_body) impure {
  if (in_msg_body.slice_empty?()) { 
    return ();
  }

  slice cs = in_msg_full.begin_parse();
  int flags = cs~load_uint(4);
  if (flags & 1) {
    on_bounce(in_msg_body);
    return ();
  }
  slice sender_address = cs~load_msg_addr();
  cs~load_msg_addr(); 
  cs~load_coins(); 
  cs~skip_bits(1); 
  cs~load_coins(); 
  int fwd_fee = muldiv(cs~load_coins(), 3, 2); 

  int op = in_msg_body~load_uint(32);

  if (op == op::transfer()) { 
    send_tokens(in_msg_body, sender_address, msg_value, fwd_fee);
    return ();
  }

  if (op == op::internal_transfer()) { 
    receive_tokens(in_msg_body, sender_address, my_balance, fwd_fee, msg_value);
    return ();
  }

  if (op == op::burn()) { 
    burn_tokens(in_msg_body, sender_address, msg_value, fwd_fee);
    return ();
  }

  throw(0xffff);
}

(int, slice, slice, cell) get_wallet_data() method_id {
  return load_data();
}


This is the wrapper for the test case in tyepscript :-

Minter Wapper :-

import {
    Address,
    beginCell,
    Cell,
    Contract,
    contractAddress,
    ContractProvider,
    Sender,
    SendMode,
    toNano,
} from '@ton/core';
import { Op } from './JettonConstatnts';

export type JettonsConfig = { admin: Address; content: Cell; wallet_code: Cell };

export type JettonMinterContent = {
    type: 0 | 1;
    uri: string;
};

export function jettonMinterConfigToCell(config: JettonsConfig): Cell {
    return beginCell()
        .storeCoins(0)
        .storeAddress(config.admin)
        .storeRef(config.content)
        .storeRef(config.wallet_code)
        .endCell();
}

export function jettonsConfigToCell(config: JettonsConfig): Cell {
    return beginCell().endCell();
}

export function jettonContentToCell(content: JettonMinterContent) {
    return beginCell().storeUint(content.type, 8).storeStringTail(content.uri).endCell();
}

export class Jettons implements Contract {
    constructor(
        readonly address: Address,
        readonly init?: { code: Cell; data: Cell },
    ) {}

    static createFromAddress(address: Address) {
        return new Jettons(address);
    }

    static createFromConfig(config: JettonsConfig, code: Cell, workchain = 0) {
        const data = jettonsConfigToCell(config);
        const init = { code, data };
        return new Jettons(contractAddress(workchain, init), init);
    }

    async sendDeploy(provider: ContractProvider, via: Sender, value: bigint) {
        await provider.internal(via, {
            value,
            sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
            body: beginCell().endCell(),
        });
    }

    protected static jettonInternalTransfer(
        jetton_amount: bigint,
        forward_ton_amount: bigint,
        response_addr?: Address,
        query_id: number | bigint = 0,
    ) {
        return beginCell()
            .storeUint(Op.internal_transfer, 32)
            .storeUint(query_id, 64)
            .storeCoins(jetton_amount)
            .storeAddress(null)
            .storeAddress(response_addr)
            .storeCoins(forward_ton_amount)
            .storeBit(false)
            .endCell();
    }

    static mintMessage(
        from: Address,
        to: Address,
        jetton_amount: bigint,
        forward_ton_amount: bigint,
        total_ton_amount: bigint,
        query_id: number | bigint = 0,
    ) {
        const mintMsg = beginCell()
            .storeUint(Op.internal_transfer, 32)
            .storeUint(0, 64)
            .storeCoins(jetton_amount)
            .storeAddress(null)
            .storeAddress(from)
            .storeCoins(forward_ton_amount)
            .storeMaybeRef(null)
            .endCell();

        return beginCell()
            .storeUint(Op.mint, 32)
            .storeUint(query_id, 64)
            .storeAddress(to)
            .storeCoins(total_ton_amount)
            .storeCoins(jetton_amount)
            .storeRef(mintMsg)
            .endCell();
    }

    async sendMint(
        provider: ContractProvider,
        via: Sender,
        to: Address,
        jetton_amount: bigint,
        forward_ton_amount: bigint,
        total_ton_amount: bigint,
    ) {
        if (total_ton_amount <= forward_ton_amount) {
            throw new Error('Total ton amount should be > forward amount');
        }
        await provider.internal(via, {
            sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
            body: Jettons.mintMessage(this.address, to, jetton_amount, forward_ton_amount, total_ton_amount),
            value: total_ton_amount + toNano('0.015'),
        });
    }

    static discoveryMessage(owner: Address, include_address: boolean) {
        return beginCell().storeUint(0x2c76b973, 32).storeUint(0, 64) 
                          .storeAddress(owner).storeBit(include_address)
               .endCell();
    }

    async sendDiscovery(provider: ContractProvider, via: Sender, owner: Address, include_address: boolean, value:bigint = toNano('0.1')) {
        await provider.internal(via, {
            sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
            body: Jettons.discoveryMessage(owner, include_address),
            value: value,
        });
    }

    async getWalletAddress(provider: ContractProvider, owner: Address): Promise<Address> {
        const res = await provider.get('get_wallet_address', [
            { type: 'slice', cell: beginCell().storeAddress(owner).endCell() },
        ]);
        return res.stack.readAddress();
    }

    async getJettonData(provider: ContractProvider) {
        let res = await provider.get('get_jetton_data', []);        
        let totalSupply = res.stack.readBigNumber();
        let mintable = res.stack.readBoolean();
        let adminAddress = res.stack.readAddress();
        let content = res.stack.readCell();
        let walletCode = res.stack.readCell();
        return {
            totalSupply,
            mintable,
            adminAddress,
            content,
            walletCode,
        };
    }

    async getTotalSupply(provider: ContractProvider) {
        let res = await this.getJettonData(provider);
        return res.totalSupply;
    }
}


2 Wallet Wrapper :-

    import { Address, beginCell, Cell, Contract, contractAddress, ContractProvider, Sender, SendMode, toNano } from '@ton/core';
    
    export type JettonWalletConfig = {};
    
    export function jettonWalletConfigToCell(config: JettonWalletConfig): Cell {
        return beginCell().endCell();
    }
    
    export class JettonWallet implements Contract {
        constructor(readonly address: Address, readonly init?: { code: Cell; data: Cell }) {}
    
        static createFromAddress(address: Address) {
            return new JettonWallet(address);
        }
    
        static createFromConfig(config: JettonWalletConfig, code: Cell, workchain = 0) {
            const data = jettonWalletConfigToCell(config);
            const init = { code, data };
            return new JettonWallet(contractAddress(workchain, init), init);
        }
    
        async sendDeploy(provider: ContractProvider, via: Sender, value: bigint) {
            await provider.internal(via, {
                value,
                sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
                body: beginCell().endCell(),
            });
        }
    
        async getJettonBalance(provider: ContractProvider) {
            let state = await provider.getState();
            if (state.state.type !== 'active') {
                return 0n;
            }
            let res = await provider.get('get_wallet_data', []);
            return res.stack.readBigNumber();
        }
        static transferMessage(jetton_amount: bigint, to: Address,
                               responseAddress:Address,
                               customPayload: Cell | null,
                               forward_ton_amount: bigint,
                               forwardPayload: Cell | null) {
            return beginCell().storeUint(0xf8a7ea5, 32).storeUint(0, 64) // op, queryId
                              .storeCoins(jetton_amount).storeAddress(to)
                              .storeAddress(responseAddress)
                              .storeMaybeRef(customPayload)
                              .storeCoins(forward_ton_amount)
                              .storeMaybeRef(forwardPayload)
                   .endCell();
        }
        async sendTransfer(provider: ContractProvider, via: Sender,
                                  value: bigint,
                                  jetton_amount: bigint, to: Address,
                                  responseAddress:Address,
                                  customPayload: Cell,
                                  forward_ton_amount: bigint,
                                  forwardPayload: Cell) {
            await provider.internal(via, {
                sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
                body: JettonWallet.transferMessage(jetton_amount, to, responseAddress, customPayload, forward_ton_amount, forwardPayload),
                value:value
            });
    
        }
        /*
          burn#595f07bc query_id:uint64 amount:(VarUInteger 16)
                        response_destination:MsgAddress custom_payload:(Maybe ^Cell)
                        = InternalMsgBody;
        */
        static burnMessage(jetton_amount: bigint,
                           responseAddress:Address,
                           customPayload: Cell | null) {
            return beginCell().storeUint(0x595f07bc, 32).storeUint(0, 64) // op, queryId
                              .storeCoins(jetton_amount).storeAddress(responseAddress)
                              .storeMaybeRef(customPayload)
                   .endCell();
        }
    
        async sendBurn(provider: ContractProvider, via: Sender, value: bigint,
                              jetton_amount: bigint,
                              responseAddress:Address,
                              customPayload: Cell) {
            await provider.internal(via, {
                sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
                body: JettonWallet.burnMessage(jetton_amount, responseAddress, customPayload),
                value:value
            });
    
        }
        /*
          withdraw_tons#107c49ef query_id:uint64 = InternalMsgBody;
        */
        static withdrawTonsMessage() {
            return beginCell().storeUint(0x6d8e5e3c, 32).storeUint(0, 64) // op, queryId
                   .endCell();
        }
    
        async sendWithdrawTons(provider: ContractProvider, via: Sender) {
            await provider.internal(via, {
                sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
                body: JettonWallet.withdrawTonsMessage(),
                value:toNano('0.1')
            });
    
        }
        /*
          withdraw_jettons#10 query_id:uint64 wallet:MsgAddressInt amount:Coins = InternalMsgBody;
        */
        static withdrawJettonsMessage(from:Address, amount:bigint) {
            return beginCell().storeUint(0x768a50b2, 32).storeUint(0, 64) // op, queryId
                              .storeAddress(from)
                              .storeCoins(amount)
                              .storeMaybeRef(null)
                   .endCell();
        }
    
        async sendWithdrawJettons(provider: ContractProvider, via: Sender, from:Address, amount:bigint) {
            await provider.internal(via, {
                sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
                body: JettonWallet.withdrawJettonsMessage(from, amount),
                value:toNano('0.1')
            });
    
        }
    }


This is the test case :-
import { Blockchain, BlockchainContractProvider, SandboxContract, TreasuryContract } from '@ton/sandbox';
import { Cell, toNano, ContractProvider, Address } from '@ton/core';
import { Jettons, jettonContentToCell } from '../wrappers/Jettons';
import '@ton/test-utils';
import { compile } from '@ton/blueprint';
import { JettonWallet } from '../wrappers/JettonWallet';
import { log } from 'console';

describe('Jettons', () => {
    let code: Cell;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        code = await compile('Jettons');
    });

    let blockchain: Blockchain;
    let deployer: SandboxContract<TreasuryContract>;
    let notDeployer: SandboxContract<TreasuryContract>;
    let jettons: SandboxContract<Jettons>;
    let minter_code = new Cell();
    let defaultContent: Cell;
    let jwallet_code = new Cell();
    let userWallet: any;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        jwallet_code = await compile('JettonWallet');
        blockchain = await Blockchain.create();
        minter_code = await compile('jettons');
        notDeployer = await blockchain.treasury('notDeployer');
        defaultContent = jettonContentToCell({ type: 1, uri: 'https://testjetton.org/content.json' });

        deployer = await blockchain.treasury('deployer');

        jettons = blockchain.openContract(
            Jettons.createFromConfig(
                {
                    admin: deployer.address,
                    content: defaultContent,
                    wallet_code: jwallet_code,
                },
                minter_code,
            ),
        );
        userWallet = async (address: Address) =>
            blockchain.openContract(JettonWallet.createFromAddress(await jettons.getWalletAddress(address)));
 
    });

    it('should deploy', async () => {
        const deployResult = await jettons.sendDeploy(deployer.getSender(), toNano('100'));

        expect(deployResult.transactions).toHaveTransaction({
            from: deployer.address,
            to: jettons.address,
            deploy: true,
        });
    });

    it('should mint jettons', async () => {
        let initialTotalSupply = await jettons.getTotalSupply();
        console.log('initialTotalSupply', initialTotalSupply);
        
        const deployerJettonWallet = await userWallet(deployer.address);
        let initialJettonBalance = toNano('1000.23');
        const mintResult = await jettons.sendMint(
            deployer.getSender(),
            deployer.address,
            initialJettonBalance,
            toNano('0.05'),
            toNano('1'),
        );

        expect(mintResult.transactions).toHaveTransaction({
            from: jettons.address,
            to: deployerJettonWallet.address,
            deploy: true,
        });

        expect(mintResult.transactions).toHaveTransaction({
            from: deployerJettonWallet.address,
            to: jettons.address,
        });

        expect(await deployerJettonWallet.getJettonBalance()).toEqual(initialJettonBalance);
        expect(await jettons.getTotalSupply()).toEqual(initialTotalSupply + initialJettonBalance);
        initialTotalSupply += initialJettonBalance;
        let additionalJettonBalance = toNano('2.31');
        await jettons.sendMint(
            deployer.getSender(),
            deployer.address,
            additionalJettonBalance,
            toNano('0.05'),
            toNano('1'),
        );
        expect(await deployerJettonWallet.getJettonBalance()).toEqual(initialJettonBalance + additionalJettonBalance);
        expect(await jettons.getTotalSupply()).toEqual(initialTotalSupply + additionalJettonBalance);
        initialTotalSupply += additionalJettonBalance;
        let otherJettonBalance = toNano('3.12');
        await jettons.sendMint(
            deployer.getSender(),
            notDeployer.address,
            otherJettonBalance,
            toNano('0.05'),
            toNano('1'),
        );
        const notDeployerJettonWallet = await userWallet(notDeployer.address);
        expect(await notDeployerJettonWallet.getJettonBalance()).toEqual(otherJettonBalance);
        expect(await jettons.getTotalSupply()).toEqual(initialTotalSupply + otherJettonBalance);
    });
});


I tried to deploy the contract inside the test case it self but not working. I am expecting that miniting process should work when i do run the test case.

beforeEach(async () => {
    jwallet_code = await compile('JettonWallet');
    blockchain = await Blockchain.create();
    minter_code = await compile('jettons');
    notDeployer = await blockchain.treasury('notDeployer');
    defaultContent = jettonContentToCell({ type: 1, uri: 'https://testjetton.org/content.json' });

    deployer = await blockchain.treasury('deployer');

    jettons = blockchain.openContract(
        Jettons.createFromConfig(
            {
                admin: deployer.address,
                content: defaultContent,
                wallet_code: jwallet_code,
            },
            minter_code,
        ),
    );

    // Deploy and activate the Jettons contract
    await jettons.sendDeploy(deployer.getSender(), toNano('1'));
    await blockchain.waitForTransaction(jettons.address, { deploy: true });

    userWallet = async (address: Address) =>
        blockchain.openContract(JettonWallet.createFromAddress(await jettons.getWalletAddress(address)));
});

you have to deploy the contract and wait for it to be deployed on the blockchain here I used blockchain.waitForTransaction
